# Migration of table from MySQL to Oracle using GoldenGate

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-12c, mysql-5.7, goldengate

I have a table of size 120 GB in MySQL 5.7 which I need to migrate to Oracle 12c. I am using [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html) for initial load of the table.

I tried with initial load of full table but it consumed complete RAM and I had to cancel it.

Even trying to run with primary key range initial load for 1/20<sup>th</sup> of table at a time, but it [abends](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abend#English) after certain time with:

> ERROR   OGG-01233  Send TCP params error: TCP/IP error 110 (Connection timed out)

Is there any better approach to get this completed?

Comment: If your program says ''Send TCP params error: TCP/IP error 110 (Connection timed out)'' then I think this means that the mysql side sends a message and does not get an answer and therefore  stops to try to communicate after waiting some time and writes this error message. So you have a communication problem- Maybe some parameters are wrong configured, your firewall does not allow the access or you have a routing problem. So I think you will not be able to send even one row to the target. So you have to solve this problem before you can use OGG.

Comment: So are you able to load a table tha has only one row?

Comment: There is an Oracle support Document [OGG-01233 Error While Starting OGG Initial Load With Large MySQL Tables (Doc ID 1903150.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1903150_1.html). Register and check the document.

Comment: MySQL has several configurable timeouts in `/etc/my.cnf` (or thereabouts); increase them.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with GoldenGate, it's better to do initial loads with database native tools.  In this case, you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME INTO OUTFILE 'filename';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Then load into Oracle with `SQL*Loader`.

Example control file for SQL Loader:

```
$ cat example1.ctl
load data
 infile '/home/ramesh/employee.txt'
 into table employee
 fields terminated by ","
 ( id, name, dept, salary )
```

Example taken from:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/oracle-sqlldr/

If you cannot stop data changes to perform the load, you need to:

- Start your extract
- Export the data
- Load the data
- start your replicat with `HANDLECOLLISIONS` enabled

After your replicat has caught up, remove `HANDLECOLLISIONS`.

For some good Tutorials, I've used https://gavinsoorma.com/category/goldengate/

Also the Oracle TechNet forums were responsive for GoldenGate questions - even for some really obscure scenarios.